# Multiple react-query api calls render dashboard UI extremely slow

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am building a react app that has a dashboard and uses react-query. On the initial load of the dashboard there are 13 query calls to multiple api endpoints that fetch the data for all of the various dashboard components.  The problem is that the initial load of the dashboard (when the user clicks the link) is extremely slow, usually taking about 7 - 9 seconds to load, and Lighthouse consistently scores the initial paint of the dashboard anywhere from 50 to 70 which is way to slow.

Prior to implementing react-query, I was loading the data using useEffect and staggering the queries using setTimeout. This was not a great approach b/c it resulted in multiple calls to the same api endpoint, but, at least the dashboard UI rendered very quickly and the data subsequently loaded.  Now that react-query is implemented, api endpoints are hit only once, however, the initial dashboard UI render takes the full 7 - 9 seconds.

One thing to note is that one component of the dashboard loads 8 of the 13 queries since it needs all the data, no way around that, and the other 5 queries are spread out over the remaining components.

I've tried implementing the setTimeout approach again to delay the loading of data in dashboard components that are not immediately visible but it doesn't seem to have any effect other than to further delay the loading of the data in those components.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to render the dashboard quicker. I should add that the problem is only on the initial render of the dashboard UI.  After the initial render, it loads very fast.

Comment: Are some of the queries returning any error . In such cases React Query retries again  after a delay which causes loading state to be extended.   In such cases you can try setting React Query not to retry if Query fails. check your network tab and see for Response times and failed queries.

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: have you checked how long the API calls actually take? How many of those 7-9 seconds are for "waiting" until those requests are finished ?